# Intercepting global name lookup in a Python exec environment

Tags: python

I realize that this may be a fragile approach, but I'm looking for a way to intercept global name lookups (and also to provide a value/binding when the lookup fails) under 'exec'.

Use case: I want to provide a restricted execution environment for some external scripts written by users.  I am trying to tailor the script conventions and namespace construction to very unsophisticated users, so I'd like them to be able to call a bunch of functions as if they were "global" without having to construct the entire dictionary by hand ahead of time.

Ergo, I'd like to intercept the global/module namespace lookup of SomeIdentifierNameTheyMayUse, and to dynamically bind that name to something computed rather than something already bound in the namespace.

Is something like this possible in general?

I managed to get something sort-of working, but it has problems, as you can see below:

```
class mydict( dict ):
    def __missing__( self, key ):
        print "__missing__:", key
        return 99

d = mydict()
d[ '__builtins__' ] = {}

code = """

# triggers __missing__ call as desired, prints 99
print this_bad_sym_is_ok 

def action1():               
   print 'action1!'

   # does not trigger __missing__.  Why?  And how can I fix it?
   print this_bad_sym_is_not

"""

exec code in d
print "d=", d
exec 'action1()' in d
```

which currently produces:

```
__missing__: this_bad_sym_is_ok
99
d= {'__builtins__': {}, 'action1': <function action1 at 0x107d6b2a8>}
action1!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 25, in <module>
    exec 'action1()' in d
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 10, in action1
NameError: global name 'this_bad_sym_is_not' is not defined
```

Even if it's not possible to do something similar to this, I'd still like to understand why it's not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this helps: https://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython

It explains the restricted execution environment.

This is an implementation: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysandbox/